# Conditional cases in cypress

Tags: puppeteer, cypress

I have a problem for writing tests for conditional cases. One of the test uses the api in 'before' (beforeAll) function to create an object, and then in test the object that was created is not shown in searching result sometimes. I was using puppeteer before. I can let the page reload until the object shows in the search result. However, there is no way for me to do the same thing. I was thinking of using cy.get and then checking the response. For instance,  `(cy.get('sth').then(s1 => {do something like cy.reload()})).`

Then, I found out that s1 always kept the same after reload. So, I am stuck.  Hope someone give me a hand to it. If the description is not clear, please the my another post below. Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand you problem very well, but I noticed you tried to inform/suggest a solution. If the problem is the async request in your before method, remember you can always pass a callback method as a parameter. Ex: before((done)=>{//call done once you have the data to set your object});

Comment: Please see my answer below. I add some details to my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry but the problem is in your before function. You gotta start it only when you are done preparing your environments to run your test.

```
const  createPerson = (params, done)=>{
  cy.request({// create people here}).then(({people})=>{
    done(undefined, {people});
  })

}

before((done)=> {
  createPerson({}, (err, {people})=>{
    cy.visit('mywebsite);
    login({}, done); // this should be async as well
  }); 
})

it('search person I created by calling api', () => {
 //if you data is not cached, at this point you will have the people populated in your screen.
 cy.get('.search')
   .type('person's name{enter}');
 cy.get(':nth-child(1) > resulttable').click();
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm gathering from your post, I think something like this may help:

```js
cy.get('some.selector').then(elem => {
    // ...
});

cy.reload();

cy.get('some.selector').then(elem => {
    // run code on element after reloading...
});
```

If this does not answer your question, please consider making a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sometimes, only calling cy.reload() once won't help since the API is unstable. Sometimes, It might need 4-5 times reload. Therefore, I have to use cy.wait (a long time) to get two nine. If the question is not clear, you can think about searching a post in google (this post was just created 2 seconds ago). For the first time, you might or might not search that post based on how fast the API call is. For this case, you might need to refresh the page. If you don't get it again, refresh and go on. By the way, appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I didn't explain my problem well. The problem is not in before() function. In before() function, I call post API to create persons. 
Then, I will use those persons created in before() function in each of my tests. 
The code would look like:

```
before(()=> {createPerson(); cy.visit('mywebsite); login();} )
it('search person I created by calling api', () => {
 cy.get('.search')
   .type('person's name{enter}');
 cy.get(':nth-child(1) > resulttable').click();
```

Here is the problem. I can't find the person in search result since the data needs time to be passed. Then, the test fails.
 So, I need reload the page (The page is searching result page) by calling
    `cy.reload();`
 However, I don't know how many reload I need to call above to let the person show up in the searching result.

The current solution I used is to `cy.wait(30000)`. wait 30 seconds.

So, I am wondering how I am going to do right now.